# Android regarding number format exception

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

```
[65,98]09-19 15:26:29.452 19498-19498/co.helpdesk.faveo.pro W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "65,98"
09-19 15:26:29.453 19498-19498/co.helpdesk.faveo.pro W/System.err:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
09-19 15:26:29.453 19498-19498/co.helpdesk.faveo.pro W/System.err:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
```

can anyone tell me how to convert this into an integer? I am getting this as 65,98 but it is telling me number format exception,

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: You cannot parse string contain with `comma (,)` in it with Integer

Comment: You can remove the `,` before parsing it to an Integer:

Comment: Then what will  be the solution? i  am getting this [65,98,66,78].....then how to convert this into integer?

Comment: It's comma separated array containing intValue you need to split from `'`

Comment: Sorry @akhilesh0707 i am not getting if you can explain me then it will be good.

Comment: just a min I'm posting a answer here

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string into int. You can use `split` method as from **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))** to parse each value separated by comma.

```
if(!yourData.isEmpty()){
    String[] result = yourData.split(",");
    int varOne = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
    int varTwo = Integer.parseInt(result[1]);
}
```